# Embedded HD video looks fuzzy on full screen but fine at Vimeo

Tags: video

Any idea as to why an embedded HD video would get fuzzy at full screen, but looks fine at Vimeo using the same full screen icon. Using the full screen icon on the video player window on this site,http://southplattebasin.com/. Seems to happen on some larger monitors. The only difference is that the HD video is embedded vs not embedded. TIA

Comment: I was able to watch it in full screen and high quality from the link you posted above. However, I had to explicitly press the "HD" icon on the timeline bar. Perhaps there's some sort of parameter you need to set when embedding it? Or perhaps Vimeo disallows HD by default when embedding?

Comment: Thanks user1118321. Question for you - After hitting the HD icon, did your "view" of the video improve? Was it less sharp prior to your using the HD icon? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, absolutely. It looked like it was maybe half res before I hit the button. After I hit the button, the jaggies went away and it was nice and crisp. (I'm on a Retina MacBook Pro, for what that's worth.)

Comment: Thanks again. I'm using a MacBook Air and see the movie in all it's crisp glory. My client is using a Windows machine : (  I'm going to have to go to their office and see first hand. Thanks again for your feedback. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

To embed a HD video hosted on Vimeo, you need Vimeo PLUS or PRO.

From [this page](https://vimeo.com/help/faq/sharing-videos/embedding-videos#can-i-make-my-embedded-videos-default-to-hd):

> Can I make my embedded videos default to HD?
>
> Plus and PRO members have the ability to not only embed their videos
>   in glorious HD, but also to default those videos to be viewed in HD.
>   This is a sweet way to make sure that your crisp, high definition
>   videos are seen in their full glory when they're embedded around the
>   interwebs.

They even made [a simple diagram](https://vimeo.com/plus) to explain it.